# Append html after node content in custom module in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming

I have an custom `tpl.php` inside of theme for some node type. It works fine but I would like my custom module to append some HTML after each such node (content of `tpl.php`). And I don't want to override the output from `tpl.php` inside of theme (just add something at the end of it).

Is there an hook for that or should I use different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [node view alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7.x) hook in your module to add/change your node object:

> This hook is called after the content has been assembled in a structured array and may be used for doing processing which requires that the complete node content structure has been built.

If you have devel enabled, you can dpm($node) inside your node_view_alter function to see the node structure and then you can add to it as needed from the module.

Comment: Sorry for a bit silly question but should the function be `function hook_node_view_alter(&$build)` or `function mymodule_hook_node_view_alter(&$build)`? I tried both but it looks like neither of them is called. Could you maybe provide sample body of this function?

Comment: Should be `mymodule_node_view_alter(&$build)`  Did you clear caches after implementing this? Can you add your code to your original question? You can also read this excellent tutorial on [understanding the hook system](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/understanding-the-hook-system-for-drupal-modules)

Comment: Thank you for the link and clarification. After clearing cache everything works fine :)